# Adding custom text after order total in Woocommerce orders and emails

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

I am using this to display a custom text for customers from specific countries on the cart and checkout page:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_order_total_html', 'custom_total_message_html', 10, 1 );

function custom_total_message_html( $value ) {
if( in_array( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), array('US', 'CA') ) ) {
    $value .= '<small>' . __('My text.', 'woocommerce') . '</small>';
}
return $value;
}
```

This does however NOT add the custom text after the order totals in the plain order emails that Woocommerce is sending. I know there is a filter `woocommerce_get_formatted_order_total` but I cannot seem to get a working function with this. How can I modify my function above to also display the custom text after the price in the plain order emails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying this custom text in WooCommerce orders and emails after total, use the following:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_order_total_message_html', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_total_message_html( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if( in_array( $order->get_shipping_country(), array('US', 'CA') ) && isset($total_rows['order_total']) ) {
        $total_rows['order_total']['value'] .= ' <small>' . __('My text.', 'woocommerce') . '</small>';
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To make it work only on email notifications use:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'custom_order_total_message_html', 10, 3 );
function custom_order_total_message_html( $total_rows, $order, $tax_display ) {
    if( in_array( $order->get_shipping_country(), array('US', 'CA') ) && isset($total_rows['order_total']) && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) {
        $total_rows['order_total']['value'] .= ' <small>' . __('My text.', 'woocommerce') . '</small>';
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Just for clarification: The first function will display the text on the "thank you/order-received" page and emails, but not on cart an checkout. The second will only display it in emails. And my original function will only display it on cart an checkout page?